# Check javascript file Proper way in functions.php

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, jquery, javascript

I am trying to convert html to wordpress.
The code in the html was:

```
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> ( jQuery v1.7.2 )
```

and The inline script

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

); and much more.
```

In wordpress functions.php , I added this

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'your_enqueue' ) ) :
    function your_enqueue(){
wp_enqueue_script(' name ', get_template_directory_uri(). '/script.js' , array('jquery')), '1.0', false);
}
endif;
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue');
```

I created a new .js file named script.js and added the following code in it:

```
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();
  }

);
```

Is it right way to do this? Will it work? and Wordpress by default uses jQuery v1.7.2 or have to do some coding again in functions.php

Answer (score 2):

Several pointers.

- The latest WordPress version uses jQuery v1.10.2 , always use the
  bundled version for admin areas , for the front end you can use the
  bundled version or a CDN.

If you use a CDN make sure to still use `jquery` as a `$handle` so it is not loaded multiple times from other plugins/themes that also enqueue jQuery.

- Use no conflict wrappers for your scripts, there are several methods
  you can read here:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers
  *this is essential*.
- Use better naming for your code, using `name` and `your_enqueue` is
  bad, try and be consistent and unique.
- There is no reason to check if a function exists unless you plan to support child themes. Try and use conditional wrappers to only load your script where it is needed.
- Not sure if it was a typo, but you do not need to include `script src=` in your .js file, this is what enqueue is doing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Wyck's answer...

In principle, what you are doing is correct for the most part. Your code as written strikes me as a bit weird though. This code...

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'your_enqueue' ) ) :
    function your_enqueue(){
      wp_enqueue_script(' name ', get_template_directory_uri(). '/script.js' , array('jquery')), '1.0', false);
    }
endif;
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue');
```

... defines your function only if no function of the same name exists, but hooks that function's name anyway, which means that a child theme could enqueue some other script instead. In fact, some child theme or plugin could define `your_enqueue` to enqueue something beside a script, like a stylesheet, and things would not work right. I would wrap the whole thing in the conditional...

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'your_enqueue' ) ) :
    function your_enqueue(){
      wp_enqueue_script(' name ', get_template_directory_uri(). '/script.js' , array('jquery')), '1.0', false);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue');
endif;
```

Or leave off the conditional entirely...

```
function your_enqueue(){
  wp_enqueue_script(' name ', get_template_directory_uri(). '/script.js' , array('jquery')), '1.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue');
```

Or what should be even more difficult to break, if your PHP sis recent enough...

```
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
  function() {
    wp_enqueue_script(' name ', get_template_directory_uri(). '/script.js' , array('jquery')), '1.0', false);
  }
);
```

Also, you don't need the `<script` part in an external Javascript file. I imagine that you are getting Javascript errors from that.

Comment: I edited my answer just before this, I forgot about the child theme thing:)

Comment: @Wyck : didn't see your edit until you pointed it out, but I'd upvoted your answer before even starting this one :)

Comment: Could you please tell where the <script inline should be used.

Comment: That script tag should not be used at all. `jquery.nicescroll.min.js` should be enqueued just like `script.js`

Comment: NO. i am asking about Javascript calling function. which will load jquery.nicescroll.min.js These are inline script in html. where should it will be in wordpress

Comment: I told you not to put the `script` tag in an external Javascript file. I don't know what you think that has to do with a "calling function". Just enqueue your scripts and it looks like it should work.

Comment: the last option has syntax error

Comment: I don't see an error. Your PHP version is probably too old. Support for that type of callback is relatively new.